# Angular - My angular application stopped working after I installed package FortAwesome

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have an angular application which worked fine but since I installed FortAwesome using

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

The application has stopped working, the error I get is

```
Error: node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/config.d.ts:25:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/swaroop/Repos/angular-task/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
```

The version of angular I use is **11.0.7**

Initially I had installed angular-fontawesome 6 which wasn't supported in Angular 11, so I uninstalled it using npm and installed angular-fontawesome 5 but I still get the same error.
I tried nuking the entire @forawesome folder in node-modules and try a fresh install, still the same error

Is there something I am doing wrong and how would I solve this issue?

Comment: You can try to run ngcc in your project..

Comment: Tried but didn't help, infact I created a brand new project and added angular-fontawesome and it stopped compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had totally overlooked the compatibility matrix at https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome. I was installing the latest version which was not compatible with my Angular version. I have now rolled back the version of fontawesome and everything works fine